# javascript tricks. Why (a,b,c) => 5

Tags: javascript

.

```
var a,b,c = function() { return 5; };
```

Variables a and b is undefined, c is function, why when we do this (a,b,c)() we have 5 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration is the same as:

```
var a;
var b;
var c = function() { return 5; };
```

or practically the same as:

```
var a;
var b;
function c() { return 5; };
```

Using `(a,b,c)` has nothing to do with the declaration, it simply returns the last operand, so `(a,b,c)()` is exactly the same as `c()` (as long as evaluating a and b doesn't have any side effects).

Comment: `c = function(){…}` is *not* the same as `function c(){…}`!

Comment: @Gumbo: Yes, they are not exactly the same, but in this case there is no practical difference. I changed the answer so that it doesn't imply that it's the exact same thing. :)

Answer (score 10):

Because `(a,b,c)` evaluates to `c`.

See the [comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Comma_Operator) operator. Works the same way in C, C++.

Comment: Definitely not in C#. It's not an operator and only works as a separator for declarations when all the declared variables have the same type. I'm pretty sure it's the same in Java.

Comment: Ah, ok. I wasn't sure about the last two :) Thanks.

Comment: What happens if b is set to the function {return 5} instead of var c?

Comment: Then c is not a function and you get: "Exception thrown: c is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

I came across the similar puzzle recently:

```
var f = function(a,b,c){
    return a, b, {x:a+b, y:a+c}
}
```

and the result of `f(1,2,3)` is `{x:3, y:4}`, so I think that the expression `(a,b,c)` always evaluates to `c`.